# SELECT Query with COUNT and INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing some difficulties since I'm not very experienced in SQL. So i have the tables:

```
 -----------------    -------------------
| membership_info |  |  client_info      |
 -----------------    -------------------
| ID (PK)         |  | client_id (FK)    |
| Name            |  | membership_id (FK)|
| Price           |  | value_paid        |
 -----------------    -------------------
```

The membership_info and client_info has the values like:

```
 --------------------------     ----------------------------------------
|  ID  |  Name   |  Price  |   | client_id | membership_id | value_paid |
 --------------------------     ----------------------------------------
|  1   | Daily   |   30    |   |     24    |       2       |     80     |
|  2   | Weekly  |   80    |   |     25    |       2       |     80     |
|  3   | Monthly |  100    |   |     26    |       3       |     100    |
 --------------------------     ----------------------------------------
```

Now the problem that I'm facing is that i cannot figure out how to query a result looking like this:

```
 -------------------------------------
| Membership Name  | Membership Count |
 -------------------------------------
|     Weekly       |         2        |
|     Monthly      |         1        |
 -------------------------------------
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name, count(*)
from client_info c
    inner join membership_info m on c.membership_id = m.id
group by name
```